# mapping over lists with `ends_with` to apply a custom error function

Tags: r

I have a list which looks like:

[image]

I am trying to `map` over it and use the `mutate` function to apply a custom function. The list is called `results` and I want to compute an error between the `preds` and another column in the data frame. The common theme of that column in all the lists is the `1` at the very end of one of the columns.

How can I compute my custom function using `contain`, `ends_with` or something similar? The column `preds` is the same in all data frames.

```
rse <- function(x, y){
  sqrt((x - y)**2)      
}

x <- map(results, ~mutate(
  error = rse(ends_with("1"), preds)
))
```

Data:

```
list(`c(5, 19)` = structure(list(date = structure(c(16801, 16802, 
16803, 16804, 16805, 16806), class = "Date"), year = c(2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), c_farolillo = c(17, 9, 8, 3, 4, 
4), plaza_eliptica = c(25, 29, 18, 11, 13, 9), c_farolillo1 = c(17, 
9, 8, 3, 4, 4), preds = c(7.08282661437988, 9.66606140136719, 
5.95918273925781, 3.81649804115295, 4.26900291442871, 3.38829565048218
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), `c(7, 1, 2, 18)` = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(16801, 16802, 16803, 16804, 16805, 16806
    ), class = "Date"), year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
    2016), pza_del_carmen = c(12, 10, 10, 6, 8, 4), pza_de_espana = c(28, 
    21, 14, 8, 10, 6), escuelas_aguirre = c(17, 24, 19, 20, 22, 
    16), retiro = c(6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 2), pza_del_carmen1 = c(12, 
    10, 10, 6, 8, 4), preds = c(15.3020477294922, 16.007848739624, 
    15.3953952789307, 9.59985256195068, 9.85349082946777, 8.42792892456055
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`.  If `results` is a `list` of `data.frame`, then `map(results, ~ .x %>% mutate_at(vars(ends_with("1")), rse, y = preds))`

Comment: My list is too big to post here. I will work on trying to take the head of some of the lists.

Comment: huh, that was easier than I thought! `lapply(results, head)` gave me a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list` of `data.frames` ('results') with `map`, then use `mutate_at` to modify the columns with names that `ends_with` "1" by applying `rse` function while speciying the 'y' as 'preds' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
results <- map(results, ~ .x %>%
                 mutate_at(vars(ends_with("1")), list(new = ~ rse(., y = preds))))
```

Comment: Thanks! But where does the rse calculation get stored?

Comment: @user8959427. It is updating those columns that have names ends with 1.  If you need to create new columns, that can be done as well.  Note that object 'results' getss updated only if `results <- map(results, ~ ...`

Comment: I see now! thanks. Is it possible to store the calculations in a different column?

Comment: @user8959427 I updated the post.  In your `list`, there is only one column that ends with "1" for the column name.  If there are more, it will looop thorugh all of those columns and append 'new' as suffix.  As there is only a single column, the code creates the new column 'new'